# CRUD functions in Flutter with a SQLite server

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, crud

I have a Flutter app that I want to have interact with an SQLite database. I have built tables that I want to interact with in the database and have its details.

```
class SafeTable extends GenericTable {
  @override
  String tableName = "safe";
  @override
  List<List<String>> fields = [
    ['id', TableHelper.integerPrimaryKey],
    ['timestamp', TableHelper.varchar255],
    ['user_id', TableHelper.varchar255],
    ['situation', TableHelper.textDefaultEmpty],
    ['is_safe', TableHelper.booleanNotNullDefaultZero]
  ];
}

class EmergenciesTable extends GenericTable {
  @override
  String tableName = "emergencies";
  @override
  List<List<String>> fields = [
    ['id', TableHelper.integerPrimaryKey],
    ['timestamp', TableHelper.varchar255],
    ['notice', TableHelper.varchar255],
    ['instructions', TableHelper.textDefaultEmpty],
    ['is_emergency', TableHelper.booleanNotNullDefaultZero]
  ];
}
```

This is how the tables are structured and I want to preform CRUD functions to read from the *`emergencies`* table and create and update in the *`safe`* table. I have looked at turorials for CRUD but they are for differently structured databases. I need to use this structure so I'm looking for CRUD that will work with this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing structure if its not strictly tied to the data flow in your project

```
  static Future<void> createTables(sql.Database database) async {
    database.execute('''
         CREATE TABLE $tableName (
         "$columnId" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
        "$columnData1" TEXT NOT NULL,
        "$columnData2" TEXT NOT NULL,
        "$columnData3" TEXT NOT NULL
         )
        ''');
    debugPrint("success!!! DB Created");
  }

  static Future<sql.Database> db() async {
    print("Measurements Database path: ${await sql.getDatabasesPath()}");
    return sql.openDatabase(
      '$tableName',
      version: _dbVersion,
      onCreate: (sql.Database database, int version) async {
        print("------- creating a table -------");
        await createTables(database);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: my understanding is that you want 2 tables, i would go about it by making 2 different database files or put then into one - go with the former. I also have 2 different unrelated tables/databases for my project